# problem installing nao_robot ros stacks

Tags: ros, nao-robot, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

installing ros on a remote pc to control nao,then i use wstool & catkin installed the humanoid_msgs & nao_robot,this is my step:

```
1,$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
2,$ wstool init
3,$ wstool set humanoid_msgs --git git://github.com/ahornung/humanoid_msgs.git
4,$ wstool update (it's successful)
5,$ source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
6,$ cd ~/catkin_ws
7,$ catkin_make  (it's successful)
8,$ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

there is no error.

i add path in my .bashrc:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace/src:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/home/cit/naoqi/naoqi-sdk-1.12.5-linux32/lib:$PYTHONPATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/cit/naoqi/naoqi-sdk-1.12.5-linux32/lib:$LD_LIBRARY$
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
```

then i follow the tutoral :

```
cit@cit-ThinkStation-S20:~/catkin_ws/src/ros_robot/nao_bringup$ roslaunch nao_bringup nao_sim.launch
[nao_sim.launch] is neither a launch file in package [nao_bringup] nor is [nao_bringup] a launch file name
```

maybe i miss something or do something wrong,i don't know,do you know?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97506/problem-installing-nao_robot-ros-stacks/) by [doudoushuixiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8281/doudoushuixiu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are missing one step of `wstool set`. I your commands, you only added humanoid_msgs, but not the nao_robot packages.

You also need to run `wstool set nao_robot --git git://github.com/ahornung/nao_robot.git` and then run `wstool update`.

By the way, do not add the NaoQI SDK to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it could break all kinds of other programs and compilations! Only add the Python NaoQi SDK to your PYTHONPATH.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [doudoushuixiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8281/doudoushuixiu/) on 2013-11-03**:
eee :( ,i use the same way to install the nao_robot,but nothing changed.
maybe there are some possibility:

1,i install the humanoid_msgs & nao_robot int this location  ~/catkin_ws/src/humanoid_msgs & nao_robot

2,my path is wrong:  export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/catkin_ws/src:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-11-04**:
Try to run `roscd nao_robot` or `roscd nao_driver`. If that fails then ROS cannot find the packages.

**Comment by [doudoushuixiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8281/doudoushuixiu/) on 2013-11-04**:
thanku.Now ,package:"nao_robot" is ok,i can "roscd" nao_robot.i'm reading the tutoral step by step,in the section1.6:Launching ROS and NAOqi.after i input the command $ roslaunch nao_driver nao_driver_sim.launch.there is an error:[No handlers could be found for logger "rosout"] it happens many times

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-11-04**:
I don't know which tutorial you are following. I updated the instructions at http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Installation/remote
They should be more clear now.